# Sharing a link in iOS: where to place an action button if not in a bar?

Tags: ios, hyperlinks, social-media, sharing, actions

I'm going to explain what I've been told to meet: I need to add a kind of "tell a friend" option within a settings menu the app already has (which is a table view). The purpose of such "tell a friend" option is to share a link with other people to invite them to download the app, either via email, sms, or social networks.

I've been reading in `iOS Human Interface Guidelines` document that it is possible to show a `Share extension` by tapping an `Action button`. It looks like this `Action button` is only suitable for navigation bars and toolbars, and here I have a problem: I think that placing the button in the navigation bar, in my scenario, could be a bit weird since what I've been told to share is a certain short text with a link, I'm not going to share a web page nor a photo which is being displayed in the current view. And I can't place a toolbar since I already have a tab bar at the bottom...

I'd appreciate some ideas to solve this scenario. My app is targeted for iOS 6+ and for both iPhone and iPad.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: If you want your draft evaluated you will probably have to share it with us, as idea gathering is not really suitable for this site.

Comment: So you want to "tell a friend" about something but not about the thing they are currently viewing? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @locationunknown I meant... I'd want to "tell a friend" about the app, not about a certain item within the app (a notice, a photo...). I just want to share a message with a link to download the app

Comment: @AppsDev There are more or less intrusive design patterns you could use for your purpose from alert that pops up after some time of use or a set of buttons on your 'settings' or 'about app' view.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an "Action" image in the table view cell. That can make users understand that will be a Share Extension.

This is an example from Reeder.

[image: reeder]